# URL-Alias for language neutral content

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I have a page with 8 languages. Most of the content is translated and have a language assigned. But there is one part of the page, where I need language neutral content to show in each language.

If I create a language neutral content, it generates the "Language Neutral" path from the URL-Alias settings. This looks basically like the English path. Thats Ok. But it looks now for every language like the english path. Only the language prefix changes:

```
/path/to/content
/de/path/to/content
/fr/path/to/content
```

Is there a way to generate programatically URL-Aliases to this node for each enabled language?

```
/path/to/content
/de/pfad/zum/inhalt
/fr/chemin/au/contenu
```

I have found something similar for Taxonomy Terms where it creates a URL-Alias for each term in each language ([Pathauto i18n Taxonomy](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto_i18n_taxonomy)). But I should have this for nodes.

How can I achieve this without creating each alias manually?

Comment: So you have 1 node and want to have 3 url aliases for it? Am i right? 

If yes, then let say url alias is generated from the title, how do you want pathauto to get translated title for other languages?

Comment: finally do you found the solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Pathauto i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto_i18n) module:

> This module provides functionality to create aliases for each
>   language. Also this module will be helpful, if you use field
>   translation and you want show node on all language with paths,
>   different from node/nid.

Answer (score 4):

I think you probably want to use a block for that language-neutral bit. As an analogy - if there's a language-neutral image that should appear for all translations, then this isn't part of the content per se. The word 'content' can be confusing, particularly when you've got a multi-lingual site, and sometimes it's useful to only call it 'content' when it's something that can stand on it's own (an 'atomic unit of content').